# Why are off-topic questions bad?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, off-topic

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the benefit to close any question which is not as per rule of SO but still useful in some way?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56616/what-is-the-benefit-to-close-any-question-which-is-not-as-per-rule-of-so-but-stil)

I commented on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887356/decibel-calculations-4-times-louder-than-100-db-closed, stating that it was completely off topic.   The OP responded with  `"and? what's your point?".`

I don't actually have a good answer.  I know I am *supposed* to close off-topic questions, but I'm not sure how to explain the reason that off-topic questions are a bad thing.  From the point of view of the user, he has asked a question, and received an answer, so what's the problem?

Comment: Thanks. I was sure this had been asked, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: "Because this is StackOverflow not Yahoo Ask!"

Comment: After I saw this was closed, I had to look to see if it was closed as off topic as a joke. \*disappointment\*

Comment: Jeff's "broken windows" theory is an important one. If we allow off-topic questions to live on, people start asking more of them, providing links to the other off-topic questions as justification why they should be allowed to ask this one. Pretty soon, it becomes unmanageable. I don't know about you, but part of the reason I enjoy the SE sites is because of their narrow, specific focus.

Comment: @Cody Gray, I agree completely - but I am a frequent user and contributor.  But I'm not sure this explanation is very satisfying to the first-time visitor who asks an off topic question.  I think rapid closing as off-topic leaves a bad impression for newbies, who may very well have real programming questions too.    I'm wondering if there is a better way to let new visitors know that this is a welcoming site, whose rules are in place to make it even better.

Comment: @AShelly: I might have more sympathy for questions that are "edge cases", where one could *conceivably* think that they could be on-topic for a programming website. Say, something about networking. Most of those *do* get migrated, as the migration paths are open for all of the common/related sites. Questions about physics really aren't programming-related in any way that I can tell. I'm not too worried about keeping newbies who can't be bothered to read the FAQ, browse other questions on the site, or follow any other clues that they're given. At least not worried enough to go out of my way.

Comment: And of course, in addition there's the sentiment that the impact on the community at large is far greater, and therefore of more import, than the possibility of offending or discouraging one individual user. I personally agree with this sentiment, and Jeff has reflected it numerous times, commenting that we're not a "small town" anymore, and we can't afford to keep small town-like values. Stack Overflow is a big city, and we've got to clean up the litter. It's unsightly and causes problems far beyond the scope of a single user feeling unaccepted and going elsewhere. Yahoo Ask will welcome them

Comment: Off-topic questions are bad, because they are off-topic and bad.